# Divider on Right of Title

Tags: html, css

I want to put an divider on right of a section title of my page like this:

[image]

I tryid this code, but here is how it is:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
<h4 class="section-title">Lastest From Blog</h4>

.section-title {
    font-size:18px;
    background-image: url('images/divider-bar.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    color: #6c6c6c;
}
```

Here is Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Chead/hrYyg/

Comment: try adjusting the `background-position`.

Comment: You can't use background-position because it is being tiled across the x-axis. How restricted are you by markup and does the background over the text need to be transparent, or just white?

Comment: the text need be on left and the background on right

Comment: i tryed that also, but as you can see without success: http://jsfiddle.net/Chead/z5jj5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go: http://jsfiddle.net/KQdcr/

Just wrap your text in a span with a white background :

```
.section-title span { background: white; padding-right: 3px; }
```

Of course this does not work if the background of your page is not a plain color.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put an `img` tag in your header and align the text with the image

```
<h4 class="section-title">Lastest From Blog <img src="images/divider-bar.png" /></h4>
```

Comment: the divider-bar.png must be repeated =/

Answer (score 0):

here you `go` [***Try this.***](http://jsfiddle.net/hrYyg/2/) Adjust the container and the width of the divider